# Visual Basic with Twain Application

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

Hello I have a small knowledge in vb so please help me. When I run my program that can access my scanner it has an error "AccessViolationExeption was unhandled" "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."

Here is my code:

```
   Public Sub CloseSource()
        Try
            Dim rc As TwRC
            If Not Equals(SelectedDataSource.Id, IntPtr.Zero) Then
                Dim guif As TwUserInterface = New TwUserInterface()

                ' tell the data source to disable its user interface
                rc = DS_Userif(appid, SelectedDataSource, TwDG.TwDG_Control, TwDAT.TwDAT_UserInterface, TwMSG.TwMSG_DisableDS, guif)

                ' tell the device manager to release the source
                rc = DSM_Ident(appid, IntPtr.Zero, TwDG.TwDG_Control, TwDAT.TwDAT_Identity, TwMSG.TwMSG_CloseDS, SelectedDataSource)

                ' set the pointer to zero
                SelectedDataSource.Id = IntPtr.Zero
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack:=2)> Public Class TW_USERINTERFACE
    Public ShowUI As Short ' TW_BOOL
    Public ModalUI As Short ' TW_BOOL
    Public hParent As UInt32 ' TW_HANDLE
End Class
```

the bool is unfortunately 4bytes
so we use short(0=false   1=true)

Answer (score -1):

From your message and code I have understood that you have the exception when you closing the scanner. I think you have the exception because scanner is not ready for closing. Please make sure that scanner is in correct state and can be closed.

Best regards, Alexander